# Highlight previous page link from which it is rendered by adding active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add active class on previous page link from which it is rendered. My working scenario is this my current active page is

> *http://localhost:52791/Apartment/Home*

from this page i rendered detail page whose link is

> *http://localhost:52791/Apartment/Details*

Detail page link is not shown anywhere except browser URL section , so i want to add active class on home page link to highlight that page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, to highlight previous page link at first you should get url of previous page by

```
var previouspage = document.referrer;
```

and applied conditions to add active class on previous page element.
Here my javascript code that will illustrate fully...

```
$(function () {
    debugger;
    var index = 0;
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var previousPage = document.referrer.substring(document.referrer.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var previousPageUrl = document.referrer.substring(document.referrer.indexOf('/') + 17);
    var activepageoffset = url.substring(url.indexOf('/') + 11,url.lastIndexOf('/'));
    if (activepageoffset == "UserInfo" || activepageoffset == "Detail")
    {
        index = 1;
    }

   $('.sidebar-menu li a').each(function () 
    {
        var currentPage = this.href.substring(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        if (currentPage == activePage) 
        {
            if ($('.sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active')) 
               { $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active'); }
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
        else if (index == 1) 
        {
            if (currentPage == previousPage) 
            {
                if ($('.sidebar-menu li').hasClass('active')) 
                {  $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active'); }
                $('.sidebar-menu a[href="' + previousPageUrl + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
             }
            }
       });
})
```

In this active page offset is added for my custom page setting that will help to avoid to check match condition of active page and previous page, because foreach loop reset value of current page , to avoid that active offset is set.